# Tick Checkbox IE Automation Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to export a file from website but for that i have to select the elements i want to export from a checkbox.

The HTML code for the checkbox i want to tick is:

```html
<input id="MainReport_ctl04_ctl09_divDropDown_ctl00" type="checkbox" name="MainReport$ctl04$ctl09$divDropDown$ctl00" onclick="$get('MainReport_ctl04_ctl09').control.OnSelectAllClick(this);" class="">
```

I've tried:

```
With IE.document.getElementsByName("MainReport$ctl04$ctl09$divDropDown$ctl00")
.Item.Click
end with
```

And

```
With IE.document.getElementsByName("MainReport$ctl04$ctl09$divDropDown$ctl00")
.Item(0).Checked = True 
End With
```

And

```
Set obj = IE.document.getElementsByName("MainReport$ctl04$ctl09$divDropDown$ctl00")
obj.FireEvent ("onclick")
```

But nothing seems to work.

Could someone help me please? Thank u in advanced!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA - Checking Checkbox in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125623/vba-checking-checkbox-in-ie)

Comment: Try `IE.document.parentWindow.execScript("$get('MainReport_ctl04_ctl09').control.OnSelectAllClick(this);")`.

Comment: @omegastripes thank u for ur answer. i tried, but it didn't tick the checkbox...

Comment: Could you please provide actual URL and expected file format and contents? That might be [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).